# How do I create a function which has a for loop to create several dataframes?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I am connecting to a SQL database using Python. I have managed to get the database connection down, but wanted to create a for loop in a function which reads in a list of strings loops it and creates several data frames but can't think of the correct logic.

```
def database_create(SQLscript,D_name):
    
    global data
    
    cur = con.cursor()
    
    for i in SQLscript:
        cur.execute(SQLscript)
    
        D_name = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(), columns = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description])
    
       return data


x = """SQL string """

y = """SQL string """

sqllist = [x,y]

data_names = [data1,data2]

database_create(sqllist, data_names)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: push it to a container like list?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable and append to it

```
dataframes = []
for _ in range(10):
    data_names = [data1,data2]
    database_create(sqllist, data_names)
    dataframes.append(database_create(SQLscript,D_name))
```

Comment: Not sure about this answer what does assigned variable i isn't used. Also data1, data 2 have not been assigned to anythign.